# Combine two kotlin flows into a single flow that emits the latest value from the two original flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

If we have two flows defined like this:

```
val someflow = flow {
    emit("something")
}
```

and another flow defined like:

```
val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow("some value")
```

Is it possible to combine the two flows into a single flow that just emits the last value emitted by either `someflow` or `stateFlow`?

The idea is that `stateFlow` might emit a value at some point in the future, but until that happens I just want whatever value `someflow` last emitted. In the "combined" flow, I would like to just take the first value emitted by `someflow` but then be able to observe the rest of the updates on `stateFlow`.

It seems like this might be accomplished with a combine function, but I just want to emit the latest emitted value between the two flows, I don't care about what the last value of one flow was.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [`flattenMerge`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flatten-merge.html) function, which executes flows as a single flow, it might be what you need. For example:

```
val numbersFlow = flowOf("1", "2", "3", "4").onEach { delay(1000) }
val lettersFlow = flowOf("A", "B", "C").onEach { delay(2000) }
flowOf(numbersFlow, lettersFlow).flattenMerge().collect {
    println("Result $it")
}
```

Prints:

```
Result 1
Result A
Result 2
Result 3
Result B
Result 4
Result C
```

So for your case it would look something like:

```
flowOf(someFlow, stateFlow).flattenMerge().collect {
    println("Result $it")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.merge(otherFlow: Flow<T>) = flow {
    this@merge.collect { value ->
        emit(value)
    }
    otherFlow.collect { value ->
        emit(value)
    }
}
```

Note that the resulting flow will only finish when both flows are completed/canceled.

Usage:

```
someFlow.merge(stateFlow).collect {
    println(it)
}
```